# SQL Select statement --- more than 1 table and specific rows in select statement

Tags: database, select, sqlclient

I would like to know what is the right way to select more than 1 table in database in SELECT statement?  Currently I'm trying with this code which executes both, but the first SELECT statemnts gets rewriten by the second `

```
        con.Open();
        ds.Clear();
        da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT id, username, ime, prezime FROM student", con);
        da.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

        da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT odjel, smjer FROM studij", con);
        da.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        da.Fill(ds);

        dg.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

        con.Close();`
```

I have been trying using AND between tables but it doesnt work

```
        con.Open();
        ds.Clear();

        da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT id, username, ime, prezime FROM student AND odjel, smjer FROM studij", con);        
        da.Fill(ds);

        dg.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

        con.Close();
```

I don't have the need to use the whole table, just some rows, so --> SELECT * FROM student, studij <--- won't do me any good.
How can I select from multiple database tables to display in a Datagrid?

Comment: You write a query with a job and a where clause.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is using

```
      "SELECT table1.name, table2.ID FROM table1, table2"  
  or with an example
       da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT student.ime, student.prezime, studij.odjel, studij.smjer FROM student, studij", con);
```